# "bug" in C++11 text by Stroustrup?

Tags: c++, c, compatibility

I found an apparent contradiction in the c++ text having to do with the result of the `c_str()` function operating on `std:strings` (in my copy, the definition and contradiction are on p1040).

First it defines the `c_str()` function as something that produces a 'C-style' (zero-terminated) string, but later it talks about how a C++ c_str value can have embed a 'C'-style, end-of-string terminators (i.e. NUL's) embedded in the string (that is defined by being NUL terminated).

Um... does anyone else feel that this is a 'stretching' of the definition of a C-string beyond it's definition?  I.e. I think what it means, is that if you were to look at the `length()` function as applied to the `string`, it will show a different end of string than using the C-definition of a z-string -- one that can contain any character except NUL, and is terminated by NUL.

I likely don't have to worry about it in my of my programs, but it seems like a subtle distinction that makes a C++ `c_str`, not really a **'C'**-string.  Am I misunderstanding this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Zero *is* nul, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It's quite possible that std::string::length() and strlen(std::string::c_str()) return different values if the string contains binary data. C_str does give a valid c-string, it just returns a pointer after all, you get the same effect if you do strlen("hello\0world")

Comment: Robert Harvey@ - yes, I wasn't meaning to create a differentiation by using synonyms.

Comment: James@ In 'C', a string cannot contain a NUL.  Thus my objection to the term `c-_str()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `c_str` function returns a pointer to the string's contents, ensuring that the data is followed by a NUL (zero) character.

```
┌─────────────data─────────────┐ end
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64 00
H  e  l  l  o  ␠   w  o  r  l  d  ␀
```

However, the string's data itself may contain a NUL character.  (This is possible because `std::string` has to store its length explicitly instead of depending on null termination.)  When this happens, `strlen(str.c_str())` will return a smaller value than `str.length()`.

```
┌─────────────data─────────────┐ end
48 65 6C 6C 6F 00 77 6F 72 6C 64 00
H  e  l  l  o  ␀   w  o  r  l  d  ␀
└────────────┘
 string seen by strlen() etc.
```

The above is the equivalent of doing `strlen("Hello\0world")` in C.  The string as seen by the C function is a left-substring of the original string.

Sometimes this causes data loss or even [a security risk](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte), but what else could `c_str()` do in this situation?

Comment: This confirms what I asked.  The thing is that I didn't like is calling a zero-containing string a 'C_str', since in C, you don't have length's and the only way to tell eol(or eos) is with a NUL/0.  Thus, IMO, those are **not** real "C"-strings in that they wouldn't be displayed, via "printf", for example, the same way.

Answer (score 3):

In C, `NULL` is the same as 0x00.  Or null is the same as zero.
And just to be clear, `NUL` is an equivalent name of `NULL`.

So Stroustrup's text is correct about how C++ `c_str` are terminated.

---

To provide a bit more context.  It's fairly common practice in C to memset a character array after creating it in order to make sure it will be null terminated.

```
char foo[20];
memset(foo, 0x00, 20);
strlen(foo);  /* Should return 0 */
```

<sub>Please forgive me if my syntax is off a bit. And for the use of magic numbers.</sub>

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, but I was trying to use them as synonyms.

Comment: `NULL` is most definitely not the same as `0x00` in C. It's an unspecified null-pointer-constant which can be implicitly converted to any pointer type. So `(void*)0` and `__builtin_null` are perfectly fine.